# Wordpress Admin Top Level Menu Item with no link

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin that requires a settings are in Wp Admin. The Menu I have created currently appears like so:

- LSMWP

  - LSMWP
  - Settings
  - Modules

I am trying to get rid of the first sub menu item so the menu appears like below, I would also like top level item to take you to 'settings':

- LSMWP

  - Settings
  - Modules

-

**Current Code:**

```
add_menu_page( 'LSMWP Settings', 'LSMWP', 'manage_options', 'lsmwp', '', '' );

add_submenu_page( 'lsmwp','LSMWP Settings','Settings','manage_options','lsmwp-settings','create_lsmwp_page','' );

add_submenu_page( 'lsmwp','LSMWP Modules','Modules','manage_options','adny-url','create_lsmwp_page','' );
```

Comment: If you put `lsmwp-settings` as the main menu slug, the submenu with same slug will overwrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found is to manipulate the sub menu text after registration.

```
function lsmwp_menu() {
   global $submenu;
   $submenu['LSMWP'][0][0] = 'Settings';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'lsmwp_menu' );
```